# Jewish Android Apps

Tags: product-recommendation, technology, phone

Does anyone have a suggestion of any jewish Android Apps such as a calendar (halachic times and dates), siddur, sefarim, kashrut/ ask a rabbi, learn Hebrew/Yiddish/ladino etc..., and jewish music apps?

Comment: I don't see how this isn't too broad. It ended up as just a list of Jewish-related apps. The question doesn't even ask for what an app they're looking for would do -- just "be Jewish". Voting to close.

Comment: @Scimonster also possibly Primarily opinion based

Comment: @Scimonster Funny though. When this was originally asked it probably wasn't too broad.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6642070#6642070 FWIW @Scimonster, yez, 6591

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an app called JStream that let's you stream Jewish music from various stations. [JStream](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.brochos.jstream)

Or for that matter, just search for Jewish on the market...

Answer (score 8):

Check out this site: http://www.jewishicommunity.com/category/mobile-apps/android
​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Rob, welcome to mi.yodeya and thank you for the useful answer! Consider registering by following the link at the top of your User page to reap all the benefits of full mi.yodeya membership.

Answer (score 8):

[OnYourWay (Uvelechtecha Baderech)](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=Uvelechtecha+Baderech&c=apps) contains a large number of Torah texts for free. It was originally made for the iPhone, but is now available on Android also (though its interface is a bit more difficult to use).

Comment: I've used the iPhone version and found *numerous* typos.

Answer (score 6):

[Orayta Jewish Books](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=orayta+books) has what seems to be a phenomenal set of Jewish books in its app.  I don't have it myself, but I'm very tempted to not only download it, but to donate to the developers as well.

Answer (score 3):

If I may toot my own horn, I have an app, "Real Clear Daf," which is packed with features to facilitate your Gemara learning (e.g. dictionary, blog, note-taking, audio shiur, etc.).

It's available for both Android and Apple and it's absolutely FREE!

Links to the App:

[image: Android App on Google play:] https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.realcleardaf.mobile&hl=en

[image: Download on iTunes:] https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/real-clear-daf/id904872089?ls=1&mt=8

Check out this video to see more about it: http://youtu.be/4uuRCNwTQJA

Enjoy!

Comment: Cool, +1....do you think you could include a direct link to the app in the Google Play Store and the Apple App Store? That would make this answer a lot better ( *and, I might add, make it a lot easier for people to get the app....* )

Comment: Sure, I've added links. Enjoy!

Comment: Cool; I'll give it a try! :)

Answer (score 1):

Also from the creator of [Jstream](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brochos.jstream) (see also [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/4586/5323)):

- A [Brochos app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brochos.app), with an easy to use list of food items and the proper brochos
- A [Sefira reminder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brochos.tizkor.sefira.lite)

*Disclaimer: I know the developer personally*