# Jewish Online Music Radio Stations

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, music

I would like to get a list of all online radio stations that only play Jewish music. Absolutely no Kol Isha, please (or better yet, specify which one's do have Kol Isha so that women will know).

I'll start off with a few I know of... Please feel free to chip in.

Comment: Your radio is a women?

Comment: @DoubleAA I guess you're saying that there's something wrong with the grammar, but I can't see it.

Comment: Your question implies your radio can produce Kol Isha. I had never heard of a female radio. Where'd you get it?

Comment: @doubleaa not following, but if ur point is that "who said recorded Kol Isha is אסור?", then yes - that's a premise of my question

Comment: Recorded Kol Isha may or may not be Asur, but it isn't Kol Isha either way. You may want to emend your question to ask for stations that don't play recorded Kol Isha.

Comment: @DoubleAA The only type of Kol Isha available via Radio Station is recorded Kol Isha. No?

Comment: If you said Kol Ish by accident people would probably figure it out too. That doesn't make it not a mistake.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.jewishbroadcast.com/

http://www.ywnradio.com/

http://www.yidlive.com/

Comment: None of these links work for me they link to other non music websites.

Answer (score 3):

Try out the [**New York Jewish Radio**.](http://www.newyorkjewishradio.com/)

Answer (score 3):

http://www.JewishMusicStream.com

They even have an option to allow you to request a specific song from their library.

Comment: Yes. But, are you sure it's run by Mostly Music?

Comment: @yydl You know, I always just assumed it was, since all the songs link to Mostly Music. But it looks more like JewishBroadcast (one of the ones you mentioned) is the one they run. I'll edit my post accordingly.

Comment: Yep. If I had to guess they link to them for advertising purposes...

Answer (score 2):

Try this radio station out: [Country Yossi - RADIO](http://www.countryyossi.com/STAGE1/main.php?page=radio_main)

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/tkqiy9zswhi3bzf/radio.m3u8?dl=0) is a list of many Jewish religious stations.

Most of them have music, many also Shiurim.

Save link as radio.m3u8 and open it in your favourite player.

If you're looking for a good player, from my experience, [aimp3](http://www.aimp.ru/) is the best Internet radio player on windows. As alternative you can use also VLC or Clementine music players.

You can also try in your browser my own jewish radio player [here](http://do34.50webs.com/pl/n/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want on-demand radio, check out [JewishMusic.fm](http://jewishmusic.fm/frame.php?url=home/).

There is also an app ([mentioned in this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/4586/5151)) that provides easy access to a bunch of Jewish Music radio stations. [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brochos.jstream&hl=en); [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/il/app/jstream/id840435290?mt=8). Some of the stations from their list:

- Chazaq Radio
- Geula.FM
- Israel 1
- JRoot Radio
- JewishBroadcast
- Jewish Music Stream
- New York Jewish Radio
- Radio Kol Chai
- Toker.FM
- plus a couple more