# Search program for seforim in Chrome OS

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, technology

A friend of mine is using a [Chromebook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromebook). While we're trying to figure out other solutions for him, I'm trying to figure out what we can do in [Chrome OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrome_OS).

One thing he'd like to do is use a program like Torat Emet or Orayta, in order to have a corpus of religious texts on his computer, so that he could look things up and search for keywords in his *seforim*.

So I'm looking for a piece of software that

- Is a search engine with *seforim* in it
- Is free, or very cheap
- Works off-line
- Is compatible with Chrome OS

( *As far as I could tell, the ones listed [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/31874/5323) either only work in Windows, or online; neither of which help my friend* )

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4563/759

Comment: @DoubleAA Do Android apps work on Chrome OS?

Comment: I'm really thinking about giving him a real OS, like Ubuntu or something....then he could use Orayta. But until then....

Comment: I guess I'm not sure.

Comment: http://lifehacker.com/how-to-run-android-apps-inside-chrome-on-any-desktop-op-1637564101 is worth a read

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Thanks for the link! That looks really useful.

Comment: You may be able to run some windows software with a crossover for android: http://www.pcworld.com/article/3097477/chromebooks/chromebooks-can-run-windows-software-with-crossover-for-android.html